# How to deploy a Yeoman project to a sub directory?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I am using the `grunt-aws-s3` plugin to deploy my `dist` folder, and it seems that when I deploy it to a sub-directory, all my assets fail aren't linked properly. For example, it keeps trying to retrieve my web font from the root at `mydomain.com/styles/fonts/font.woff` instead of `mydomain.com/staging/styles/fonts/font.woff`. Also, it keeps trying to grab my templates via http instead of https. I tried various methods for linking my CSS (relatively, and just the filename) and none of them seem to work. How can I fix this?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'moneytree';
  src:url('/styles/fonts/webfont.eot');
  src:url('/styles/fonts/webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('/styles/fonts/webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('/styles/fonts/webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('/styles/fonts/webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}


module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // This creates a config file with a bunch of constants for Angular and then we load it into setting.coffee
    ngconstant: {
      options: {
        space: '  ',
        name: 'envConfig',
        dest: '.tmp/scripts/initializers/env-config.js',
        wrap: '"use strict";\n\n {%= __ngModule %}'
      },
      // Environment targets
      development: {
        constants: {
          ENV: {
            name: 'development',
            app_id: '',
            secret: '',
            host: 'https://test.com',
            version: 'v8/api'
          }
        }
      },
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      options: {
        nospawn: false,
        livereload: true
      },
      coffee: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.{coffee,litcoffee,coffee.md}'],
        tasks: ['newer:coffee:dist']
      },
      coffeeTest: {
        files: ['test/unit/**/*.{coffee,litcoffee,coffee.md}'],
        tasks: ['newer:coffee:test', 'karma']
      },
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/unit/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },
    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ],
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/unit/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Adds browser vendor prefixe to the CSS styles. For example, give the selector
    // :fullscreen a {}, it will generate all the different browser prefixes such as :-webkit-full-screen a {}, etc..
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
          ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
          ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
      }
    },

    // Compiles CoffeeScript to JavaScript
    coffee: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceRoot: ''
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
          src: '**/*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/scripts',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      unit: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/unit',
          src: '**/*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/unit',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      e2e: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/e2e',
          src: '**/*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/e2e',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: 'bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated',
          relativeAssets: false
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
          imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          relativeAssets: false
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/transactions*/*.svg',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        root: '<%= yeoman.app %>'
      }
    },

    imagemin: {
      options: { cache: false },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '**/*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    // Makes your minification safe for Angular's dependecy injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      options: {
        // Task-specific options go here.
        singleQuotes: true
      },
      dist: {
        // Target-specific file lists and/or options go here.
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
            src: '*.js',
            dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '**/*.{jpg,ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}{,*/}*.html',
            'images/**/*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/*'
          ]
        },
        {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/styles/fonts',
            src: ['**'],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/styles/fonts'
        },
        {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'coffee:dist',
        'compass:server'
      ],
      test: [
        'compass:test',
        'coffee:e2e',
        'coffee:dist'
      ],
      unitTest: [
        'compass:test',
        'coffee:unit',
        'coffee:dist'
      ],
      dist: [
        'coffee:dist',
        'compass:dist',
        'imagemin:dist',
        'svgmin:dist'
      ]
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },
    protractor: {
      options: {
        // You NEVER want this because if there is an error, it will not return the correct exit status
        keepAlive: false,
        configFile: 'protractor.conf.js',
        noColor: false
        //debug: true
      },
      run: {}
    },
    aws: grunt.file.readJSON('aws-keys.json'), // Read the file
    aws_s3: {
      options: {
        region: 'ap-northeast-1',
        uploadConcurrency: 5, // 5 simultaneous uploads
        downloadConcurrency: 5 // 5 simultaneous downloads
      },
      staging: {
        options: {
          bucket: 'staging-bucket',
          differential: true, // Only uploads the files that have changed
          params: {
            CacheControl: "no-cache,no-store"
          }
        },
        files: [
          {dest: '/test', 'action': 'delete'},
          {expand: true, cwd: 'dist/', src: ['**'], dest: '/test'}
        ]
      },
      clean_production: {
        options: {
          bucket: 'my-wonderful-production-bucket',
          debug: true // Doesn't actually delete but shows log
        },
        files: [
          {dest: 'app/', action: 'delete'},
          {dest: 'assets/', exclude: "**/*.tgz", action: 'delete'}, // will not delete the tgz
          {dest: 'assets/large/', exclude: "**/*copy*", flipExclude: true, action: 'delete'}, // will delete everything that has copy in the name
        ]
      },
      download_production: {
        options: {
          bucket: 'my-wonderful-production-bucket'
        },
        files: [
          {dest: 'app/', cwd: 'backup/', action: 'download'}, // Downloads the content of app/ to backup/
          {dest: 'assets/', cwd: 'backup-assets/', exclude: "**/*copy*", action: 'download'}, // Downloads everything which doesn't have copy in the name
        ]
      },
      secret: {
        options: {
          bucket: 'my-wonderful-private-bucket',
          access: 'private'
        },
        files: [
          {expand: true, cwd: 'secret_garden/', src: ['*.key'], dest: 'secret/'},
        ]
      },
    },
    dom_munger: {
      e2e: {
        options: {
          append: {
            selector: 'body',
            html: '<script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>\
            <script src="e2e/httpbackend_setup.js"></script>'
          }
        },
        src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        dest: '.tmp/e2e.html'
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'ngconstant:development',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build:development', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'ngconstant:development',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('deploy:staging', [
    'build:development',
    'aws_s3:staging'
  ]);
```

---

**Edit:** I managed to get the fonts in the CSS working relatively, but still can't get the HTML embedded images to load relatively. Also, still dont understand why my font is being retrieved over HTTP as opposed to HTTPS causing a mixed content error from the browser.

Assuming you have your fonts in `app/styles/fonts` (noticed the `font-url` function as opposed to `url()`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'webfont';
  src: font-url('webfont.eot');
  src: font-url('webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
   font-url('webfont.woff') format('woff'),
   font-url('webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   font-url('webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

For my compass (httpFontsPath) and cssmin (noRebase) config in the Gruntfile:

```
  compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: 'bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: 'images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: 'fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
      }
}



cssmin: {
  options: {
    root: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
    noRebase: true
  }
}
```

Comment: It'd be easier for us if we can take a look at your Gruntfile.js code.

Comment: I think you need to explain the protocol part better. Which templates are served over the wrong protocol? How are you serving them?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your paths relative, for example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'moneytree';
  src:url('fonts/webfont.eot');
  src:url('fonts/webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fonts/webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('fonts/webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```